# id auto field error when saved in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models

I will paste only the necessary code of my issue.
I have the following model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name')

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("before")
        print(validated_data)
        event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print("after")

        return event
```

I get on line  `event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)` the following error `null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint` . When i print the validated data it does not includes any id. How do i solve my issue ?

Comment: you may have wrong entries in db

Comment: I migrate zero and re-migrate in order to be sure

Answer (score 0):

In DRF `AutoField` fields are defaulted to read-only, You can override this behavior by defining `extra_kwargs`

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField() # Here
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': False}}

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("before")
        print(validated_data)
        event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)
        print("after")

        return event
```